# Wordpress detect plugins when wpscan fails

Tags: wordpress, web-scanners

I was provided a challenge from a friend, where I have a latest wordpress installation with a vulnerable plugin. I was requested to detect the vulnerability so for that I used `wpscan` in order to do that, for that I did it on a graybox basis knowing that is a wordpress site with some plugins.

But somehow `wpscan` fails to detects the installed plugins, therefore I need some sort of "directory scanning" tool where I can scan on `wp-content/plugin` folder from a plugin list in order to list which wordpress plugins have been installed based on "signature paths" or "signature http requests" eg if `/wp-content/plugin/my-plugin/somefile.php` exists then it may have been installed the `my-plugin`.

The idea is to "scan" an http directory with specific patterns in order to enumerate its files. Is that feasible even if the webserver is configured **NOT** to show the files and directories?

I know I can click around the website and get the vague idea which plugin uses but sometimes plugins do not have visible signs that exist to the webpage's html eg backup ones.

Comment: `wpscan` *is* a bruteforce dictionary tool

Comment: But also detects plugins for wordpress, wordpress version and installed theme as well (sometimes).

Comment: What I'm saying is that I'm confused. A bruteforce tool didn't work, so you want a bruteforce tool... I think that you need to investigate why `wpscan` didn't work.

Comment: I am not brute forcing the password but for scanning a website for hidden directories and files without relying on website's html.

Comment: I also improved the question  in order to be more understandable.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. Brute force is not only for passwords. Brute force processes can also be used to find files and directories, just like you describe. And wpscan does this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78388/discussion-between-dimitrios-desyllas-and-schroeder).